# How to not display products with '1' stock

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, product

can someone help me? I need to not display products on woocommerce that have only 1 in stock. I wrote a css that does that but the problem is not solving.

```
.stock in-stock[data-disponibili="1 available"] {
  display: none;
}
```

i also tried

```
p.stock.in-stock:contains("1 disponibili") {
  display: none;
}
```

But with no result

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML?

Comment: this is the html class `<p class="stock in-stock">1 disponibili</p>`

Comment: That does not have any `data-disponibili` attribute to begin with, so what is the point of your first "attempt" here then? (Plus there is likely no element named `in-stock` either.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like WooCommerce has a native function that should solve your issue:

In your WordPress Dashboard, click on inventory on the dashboard on the left and enter relevant product details like stock-keeping unit (SKU), stock quantity, stock status – whether the quantity is in stock or out of stock, etc.
If you are getting out of inventory and want to delete the stock, you can manage it from the above dashboard. You can also update your stock from the same page.

[image: Screenshot of inventory dashboard]

Choose whether to enable stock management. If selected, you have this option:

**Enter an Out of Stock Threshold – The value in this field will determine the point in which a product is out of stock  (typically 0; in your case probably 1).**

[image: Screenshot of Threshold config]

I found this on https://www.awardspace.com/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-hide-out-of-stock-products-in-woocommerce/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33854764)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Hope my edited answer complies with the best-practices here :) Let me know if it worked, Ilyas, and if my answer solved your issue, feel free to accept it so other users know that it was tested and that it proved to be helpful.